# Flutter FutureBuilder resolving multiple times without build() being called

Tags: flutter

I'm having an issue with my widget running its `FutureBuilder` code multiple times with an already resolved `Future`. Unlike the other questions on SO about this, my `build()` method isn't being called multiple times.

My future is being called outside of `build()` in `initState()` - it's also wrapped in an `AsyncMemoizer`.

Relevant code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late final Future myFuture;
  final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// provider package
    final homeService = context.read<HomeService>();
    myFuture = _memoizer.runOnce(homeService.getMyData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("[HOME] BUILDING OUR HOME SCREEN");

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: myFuture,
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        print("[HOME] BUILDER CALLED WITH SNAPSHOT: $snapshot - connection state: ${snapshot.connectionState}");
```

When I run the code, and trigger the bug (a soft keyboard being shown manages to trigger it 50% of the time, but not all the time), my logs are:

```
I/flutter (29283): [HOME] BUILDING OUR HOME SCREEN
I/flutter (29283): [HOME] BUILDER CALLED WITH SNAPSHOT: AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null) - connection state: ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter (29283): [HOME] BUILDER CALLED WITH SNAPSHOT: AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.done, Instance of 'HomeData', null, null) - connection state: ConnectionState.done
...
/// bug triggered
...
I/flutter (29283): [HOME] BUILDER CALLED WITH SNAPSHOT: AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.done, Instance of 'HomeData', null, null) - connection state: ConnectionState.done
```

The initial call with `ConnectionState.waiting` is normal, then we get the first build with `ConnectionState.done`.

After the bug is triggered, I end up with another `FutureBuilder` resolve *without* the `build()` method being called.

Am I missing something here?

**Edit with full example**

This shows the bug in question - if you click in and out of the TextField, the `FutureBuilder` is called again.

It seems related to how the keyboard is hidden. If I use the `FocusScopeNode` method, it will rebuild, whereas if I use `FocusManager`, it won't, so I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Testapp',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: TestAppHomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestAppHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestAppHomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestAppHomeScreen> createState() => _TestAppHomeScreenState();
}

class _TestAppHomeScreenState extends State<TestAppHomeScreen> {
  late final Future myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myFuture = Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => true);

    print("[HOME] HOME SCREEN INIT STATE CALLED: $hashCode");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("[HOME] HOME SCREEN BUILD CALLED: $hashCode");
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: myFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("[HOME] HOME SCREEN FUTURE BUILDER CALLED WITH STATE ${snapshot.connectionState}: $hashCode");
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }

        return GestureDetector(
          onTapUp: (details) {
            // hide the keyboard if it's showing
            FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
              currentFocus.unfocus();
            }
            // FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
          },
          child: const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                child: TextField(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this, could you be more specific about this "bug" you're referring about? Could you post a full reproducible example?

Comment: I've added a reproducible example @venir

Comment: I've answered below. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the full, reproducible example.

`print` statements inside the `builder` method of your `FutureBuilder` are likely misleading you towards the incorrect "culprit".

The key "problem" arises from this line:

```dart
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
```

In case you didn't know, Flutter's `.of` static methods expose [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) APIs of some kind. By convention, in a `.of` method you can usually find a call to `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`, which *is meant* to register the caller, i.e. the children `Widget`, as a *dependency*, i.e. a `Widget` that depends and react to changes of a `InheritedWidget` of that type.

Shortly, putting a `.of` inside a `build` method **is meant to** trigger rebuilds on your `Widget`: it's actively registered for listening to changes!

In your code, `FutureBuilder`'s `builder` method is being registered as dependant of `FocusScope.of` and will be rebuilt if `FocusScope` changes. And yes, that does happen whenever we change focus. Indeed, you can even move up those few lines (outside `GestureDetector`, directly in the `builder` scope), and you'd obtain even more rebuilds (4: one for the first focus change, then others subsequent caused by the focus shift caused by such rebuilds).

One quick fix would be to directly look for the associated `InheritedWidget` these API expose, and then, instead of a simple `.of`, you'd call:

```dart
context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<T>();
```

**EDIT.** I just looked for `T` in your use case. Unluckily, it turns out it is a `_FocusMarker extends InheritedWidget` class, which is a private class, and therefore it cannot be used outside of its file / package. I'm not sure why they designed the API like that, but I am not familiar with `FocusNode`s.

An alternative approach would be to simply isolate the children for your `FutureBuilder`, like so:

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  print("[HOME] HOME SCREEN FUTURE BUILDER CALLED WITH STATE ${snapshot.connectionState}: $hashCode");
  // ...
  return Something();
}
```

Where `Something` is just the refactored `StatelessWidget` that contains the UI you've shown there. This would rebuild just `Something` and not the whole `builder` method, if that's your concern.

You want to deepen the "how" and the "whys" of `InheritedWidget`s, make sure you first watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk) to correctly understand what `InheritedWidget`s are. Then, if you wish to understand how to exploit `didChangeDependencies`, watch [this other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og-vJqLzg2c) and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I completely zapped that calling the `.of` methods registers the widget to be rebuilt. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @divillysausages `.of` methods only registers the widget to rebuild if the call is used *directly* inside the `build()` method not anywhere else.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad you're telling me that calling `.of` inside a `didChangeDependencies` won't trigger calls on `build`? To my knowledge, it does. `didChangeDependencies` is used to cache values outside of `build` (it could be useful when `build` is called multiple times, independently of `.of`)... but that still counts as a dependency.

Comment: @venir No, I didn't mean that. In the code, OP is using `Focus.of(context)` in a callback which is neither inside `build` nor `didChangeDependencies` and therefore a build shouldn't be triggered by it.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad does the `builder()` method not count as a `build()` method in your case?

Comment: @divillysausages `builder()` is a `build()` but your `FocusScope.of(context)` was not inside `build` or `builder`, it was inside `onTap` which is a callback. So, using `FocusScope.of(context)` inside the callback won't setup a listener. You can read my answer for better understanding why the `build()` wasn't getting called.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I don't get it. He's using the inner `context` inside that callback, thus `builder` gets registered as a dependency. How does the location influence that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the role of **`BuildContext`**.

##### Example-1:

I'm using `context` passed to the `Widget.build()` method, and doing

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

will invoke both `build()` and `builder()` method because you're telling Flutter to take the focus away from any widget within the `context` and therefore the `Widget.build()` gets called, which further calls the `Builder.builder()` method.

```dart
// Example-1
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Widget.build()");

  return Builder(builder: (context2) {
    print('Builder.builder()');
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(), // <-- Using `context`
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

---

##### Example-2:

I'm using `context2` passed to the `Builder.builder()` method, and doing

```
FocusScope.of(context2).unfocus();
```

will invoke only the `builder()` method because you're telling Flutter to take the focus away from any widget within the `context2` and thus the `Builder.builder()` gets called.

```dart
// Example-2
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Widget.build()");

  return Builder(builder: (context2) {
    print('Builder.builder()');
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context2).unfocus(), // <-- Using `context2`
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

---

To answer your question, if you replace

```
builder: (context, snapshot) { ...}
```

with

```
builder: (_, snapshot) { }
```

then your `build()` will also get called.

Answer (score 1):

- The difference was happen because the `context` you use is parent
  context (from future builder method).
  Just wrap GestureDetector with Builder then the result is same as 2nd way.

  ```
       return Builder(builder: (_context) {
         return GestureDetector(
           onTapUp: () {
             // hide the keyboard if it's showing
             final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(_context);
             if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
               currentFocus.unfocus();
             },
           } ...
  ```
- When attempting to dismiss keyboard we should use second way `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();` as discussion in official issue here:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20227#issuecomment-512860882
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19552

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution  `/// provider package` up `super.initState();`

your code will be like this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    /// provider package
    final homeService = context.read<HomeService>();
    myFuture = _memoizer.runOnce(homeService.getMyData);
    super.initState();
  }
```

please after trying it tell me the result

Comment: It hasn't made a difference unfortunately

Comment: do you have any setState

Comment: I've updated the question with a reproducible example - it seems related to how focus is removed from the keyboard

Comment: is your problem that future builder work twice the first one is waiting and the second one is done state - or is your problem when pressing on textfield the builder work again

Comment: according to what i see when you press on textfield flutter refresh the state and rebuild the page that mean flutter will build the FutureBuilder again as a widget without calling the future again only building process.

The calling process happens only one time but the building process happen in every setState. if my thinking is right that mean this behaviour is normal

Answer (score 0):

pass descendant `context` to `FocusScope.of` will not trigger the `build()`, i think because focus manager remove child for this parent (FutureBuilder), and reassign it based on current context, in this case `build()` context, so futurebuilder need to rebuild.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("[HOME] HOME SCREEN BUILD CALLED: $hashCode");
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: myFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("[HOME] HOME SCREEN FUTURE BUILDER CALLED WITH STATE ${snapshot.connectionState}: $hashCode");
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
        //make StatefulBuilder as parent will prevent it
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTapUp: (details) {
                // hide the keyboard if it's showing
                FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                  currentFocus.unfocus();
                }
                // FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
              },
              child: const Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

to prove it , i try to warp it parent (`FutureBuilder`) with another builder :

```
return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, box) {
        print('Rebuild');
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: myFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print("[HOME] HOME SCREEN FUTURE BUILDER CALLED WITH STATE ${snapshot.connectionState}: $hashCode");
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }

            return GestureDetector(
              onTapUp: (details) {
                // hide the keyboard if it's showing
                FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                  currentFocus.unfocus();
                }
                // FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
              },
              child: const Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );


          },
        );
      }
    );
```

`build()` method not reinvoked because focusScope manager only rebuild context from `FutureBuilder` (Parent)